# Google Cloud Run deployment cannot find file in ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I am following the Google documentation to upload my docker file into the cloud console:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python_1

I changed the `main.py` file to my own `app.py` which uses Flask. My local Dockerfile is defined as:

```
# Copyright 2020 Google, LLC.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START cloudrun_helloworld_dockerfile]
# [START run_helloworld_dockerfile]

# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app

ENTRYPOINT ["app.py"]

# [END run_helloworld_dockerfile]
# [END cloudrun_helloworld_dockerfile]
```

I am not sure if `ENTRYPOINT` is need but without it the service does nothing, complains about not `main.py` has been found. I can upload the image to the Cloud Run using`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/projectid/webhook` , but the deployment will fail both using gcloud console or locally. The error says:

```
Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [\
name: "gcr.io/projectid/webhook@sha256:706cd97430e6537f91b0ac8c67262ba6a0c10f961c04a4d918ea1649bcead4e3" \
error: "Invalid command \"app.py\": \
file not found anywhere in PATH \"/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\"" ].
```

Why is the file not found? I thought the Dockerfile will instruct to copy everything in the local directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the application working. I did not use ENTRYPOINT in the end, the default CMD exec gunicorn was sufficient. The mistake I have made was the same line, the final argument was main:app, which specifies the variable app in the main.py. I have named my script app.py, so it was complaining it was not found. After fixing the issue the error is solved.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to know the difference between the `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands as they run at different times during the container build.

**RUN**

The `RUN` command(s) executes in a new layer and creates a new image, for example, to install software packages. The command runs on top of the current image and creates a new layer by committing the results. Often you will find multiple `RUN` instructions in a Dockerfile.

**CMD**

The `CMD` sets a default command or parameters, which can be overwritten from the command line when docker container runs. If a Docker container has a `CMD` command, only the last `CMD` instruction executes and the default ignored.

**ENTRYPOINT**

The `ENTRYPOINT` configures a container that will run as an executable. It appears similar to `CMD`, but the main difference is `ENTRYPOINT` is NOT ignored when the Docker container runs.